# AngularJS directive restrict by comment

Tags: angularjs-directive

I have created directive as:

```
app.directive("myDirective", function () {
        alert("Directive Created.");
        return {
            restrict: 'M',
            template: "<div id='divInner' style='background-color:red;'>Inside Division</div>"
        };
    });
```

and use the directive as:

```
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="controller">
    <div id="divOuter">
        <!-- directive: my-directive -->
    </div>
</body>
```

the code does not work.
Please correct the code.